# Creating custom annotation in Java

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I'm adding some logs to my Spring based application, I want to log for every method, the user that is doing the action. Below you can find an example of a method.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteAccount(Long id){
    String principal = (String) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    MDC.put("username",principal);
    accountDao.remove(id);
    List<String> action = (List<String>) MDC.get("action");
    if (action == null)
        action=new ArrayList<String>();
    action.add("Deleted account with id:"+id);
    MDC.put("action", action);
}
```

The first two lines of the method are generic, so I want two avoid to add these two lines in every method:

```
String principal = (String) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    MDC.put("username",principal);
```

So I was thinking to create a custom annotation to get the user and to put it in the MDC log. This way I could just apply this annotation to the methods I need this log, I'm not sure how to accomplish that, could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: I would say use Aspect instead of annotation for implementing your logic. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.htm should help running your global lines of code asynchronously.

Answer (score -7):

Use C-macro for this.. No, seriously, why not to use C-preprocessor for this? Just define macro for this two lines using `#define` and then give file with it to preprocessor. It must work.

UPD. Do it like this:

```
#define MDCLOG {
    String principal = (String) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    MDC.put("username",principal);
}
public void deleteAccount(Long id) {
    MDCLOG
    accountDao.remove(id);
    List<String> action = (List<String>) MDC.get("action");
    if (action == null)
        action=new ArrayList<String>();
    action.add("Deleted account with id:"+id);
    MDC.put("action", action);
}
```

Comment: I know, but my idea can be better than annotations or aspects. C-preprocessor doesn't have any requests on file

Comment: that may be right. but it will not help the OP - (s)he is not likely to rewrite the code in C.

Comment: He don't need to rewrite code in C. He just need to use #define. C-preprocessor will do all work

Comment: Java reached its popularity because it did not do things like this. And besides that, Java has many build- and runtime (pre)processors on its own.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic yes, but in this case it is easier to use C-preprocessor than to write your own

Comment: Show us how you'd do that in your answer please.

Comment: Note that this would require running the preprocessor just to make the code compilable which is an obvious non-starter. If you really wanted to go in this direction it would be much more practical to create an IDE macro to replace the "MDCLOG" string with arbitrary Java code.

Comment: @kryger oh, yes. I didn't think about this